# Django rest framework, Method \"DELETE\" not allowed while using @action decorator

Tags: django-rest-framework, decorator, django-urls

I have 2 method for `GET` and `DELETE` operation

```
path('reporting/reports/<str:report_id>', ReportView.as_view({"get": "get_report"}), name="get_report"),

path('reporting/reports/<str:report_id>', ReportView.as_view({"delete": "delete_reports"}), name="delete_reports"),
```

and the view is made using `@action` decorator

```
class ReportView(ViewSet):
    @action(methods=["GET"], detail=False)
    def get_report(self, request, report_id):
        pass
    @action(methods=["DELETE"], detail=False)
    def delete_reports(self, request, report_id)
        pass
```

The URL that made are during check url from browser

```
reporting/reports/<str:report_id> [name='get_report']
reporting/reports/<str:report_id> [name='delete_reports']
```

Here the `GET` methods work, but `DELETE` method does not work.

If I change the sequence of urls, the `DELETE` method works and `GET` does not work

Following message I get in response

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"DELETE\" not allowed."
}
```

Comment: What does `print(ReportView.http_method_names)` says.

Comment: ReportView.http_method_names=['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']

Answer (score 1):

You should include both method routes in the same path, otherwise it will always take the first, and there there is only a route for the `get` path, so:

```
path(
    'reporting/reports/<str:report_id>',
    ReportView.as_view({'get': 'get_report', 'delete': 'delete_reports'}),
    name='report',
)
```